# How to create buffers having regard to topography with QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, elevation, topography

I want to create buffers of 25 kilometers around points in a point-shapefile with QGIS.

My problem is that I don't need an air-line distance of 25 km around the points, but a "real distance" having regard to the DEM of the area.

In other words, it should be visible, how far (in air-line distance) I could walk in each direction of a point, always walking exact 25 km.

I loaded the DEM raster in my project and buffered my point-shapefile, but I have no idea how to combine both, so that QGIS fits the buffers into the elevation model.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129396/how-to-compute-walking-and-cycling-isochrone-maps-using-qgis-pgrouting

Comment: This might also help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118506/how-to-measure-distance-between-points-based-on-elevation